# Why is file deletion directly from website code a bad idea

Tags: asp.net, workflow

We have a typical ASP.NET website which customers interact with. Management has a new requirement that when a user submits a certain page, and a certain workflow ensues, the code should now directly make a typical file IO call to delete some processing files from a fileserver location not on the web server itself.

We have things coded in code behinds, as usual. I say this is a bad idea and instead the code should simply queue up some kind of request to delete file in our backend db and let some other behind the scenes process do the deleting.

I know this is the right idea but I can't explain why other than "separation of concerns" is good.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you edit your title to be more descriptive? Something like "Why is separation of concerns a good thing?", or be more specific about what the "this" referenced in your title is.

Comment: Because a website is not the right tool to delete files. It is typically used by multiple users parallel. So i agree with you that it would be better to let the site only store into db what should be deleted. But the processing itself should be done from a windows-service (for example). Possible problems with webseite: authentication, IO-problems due to locking, timeout because deleting is time consuming, other exceptions, duplicate deletes, ...